# How to do code coverage for Catch Block:

Tags: apex, code-coverage, try-catch

Below is my apex class:

```
public void submitForApproval(List<Account> acc)
{

    try{

        for(SObject ac :acc) {

            if((ac.Account_Record_Type_Name__c == 'A' || ac.Account_Record_Type_Name__c == 'B') &&  ac.Status__c == 'New'){
                // Create an approval request for the Account
                Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest submitRequest = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
                submitRequest.setComments('Submitting request for approval');
                submitRequest.setObjectId(ac.id);
                submitRequest.setSubmitterId(ac.CreatedById); 
                submitRequest.setProcessDefinitionNameOrId('Account for Approval');           
                Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.process(submitRequest);    
                system.debug('Result ' + result.isSuccess() + 'NewObj ID' + ac.Id);
            }
        }

    }catch(Exception ex){
        system.debug('Exception in Approval Process submision and error is--->'+ex);

        Batch.trackErrorLog(CLASS_NAME, 'submitForApproval',
                                    'Exception Line Number:' + ex.getLineNo() +
                                    'Exception Type' + ex.getType()+                                                             
                                    'Exception Message' + ex.getmessage());
    }

}
```

I tried to write a test class like this:

```
Account testdelAcc=new Account(Name = 'Test DelAcc');

try{
    testdelAcc.RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Account.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('ABC').getRecordTypeId();
    insert testdelAcc;
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    system.assertEquals(e.getMessage(), e.getMessage());
}
```

I am trying to pass Invalid Record Type but it does not cover the catch block.
Can someone help me what I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

The way you have written test method logic, it will never enter in `catch` block as in your main class you are not throwing an exception when recordtype is Invalid.

`submitForApproval` method will throw the exception if system is unable to process the submit for approval.

You can change your code as below if possible.

> **Approach 1**

Pass `processDefinitionNameOrId` as an argument to this method

```
public void submitForApproval(List<Account> acc, String processDefinitionNameOrId)
{

    try{

        for(SObject ac :acc) {

            if((ac.Account_Record_Type_Name__c == 'A' || ac.Account_Record_Type_Name__c == 'B') &&  ac.Status__c == 'New'){
                // Create an approval request for the Account
                Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest submitRequest = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
                submitRequest.setComments('Submitting request for approval');
                submitRequest.setObjectId(ac.id);
                submitRequest.setSubmitterId(ac.CreatedById); 
                submitRequest.setProcessDefinitionNameOrId(processDefinitionNameOrId);           
                Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.process(submitRequest);    
                system.debug('Result ' + result.isSuccess() + 'NewObj ID' + ac.Id);
            }
        }

    }catch(Exception ex){
        system.debug('Exception in Approval Process submision and error is--->'+ex);

        PSABatchUtil.trackErrorLogs(CLASS_NAME, 'submitForApproval',
                                    'Exception Line Number:' + ex.getLineNo() +
                                    'Exception Type' + ex.getType()+                                                             
                                    'Exception Message' + ex.getmessage());
    }
}
```

**Test Class**

From the test method, pass invalid process definition Id for which System will throw the exception.

One more point, your `assert` statement. What you are trying to compare with the `assertEquals()` when you are putting both expected output in both the arguments.

Follow best practices writing test class.

```
Account testdelAcc=new Account(Name = 'Test DelAcc');

YourClass cls = new YourClass();

    insert testdelAcc;
    List<Account> lstAccount = new List<Account>();
    lstAccount.add(testdelAcc);
    cls.submitForApproval(lstAccount, 'any invalid processDefinitionNameOrId');
   //check any values create in PSABatchUtil.trackErrorLogs
```

> **Approach 2**

Without changing method signature, you could declare a variable for `processDefinitionNameOrId`

```
@TestVisible private String processDefinitionNameOrId = 'Account for Approval' ;

public void submitForApproval(List<Account> acc)
{

    try{

        for(SObject ac :acc) {

            if((ac.Account_Record_Type_Name__c == 'A' || ac.Account_Record_Type_Name__c == 'B') &&  ac.Status__c == 'New'){
                // Create an approval request for the Account
                Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest submitRequest = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
                submitRequest.setComments('Submitting request for approval');
                submitRequest.setObjectId(ac.id);
                submitRequest.setSubmitterId(ac.CreatedById); 
                submitRequest.setProcessDefinitionNameOrId(processDefinitionNameOrId);           
                Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.process(submitRequest);    
                system.debug('Result ' + result.isSuccess() + 'NewObj ID' + ac.Id);
            }
        }

    }catch(Exception ex){
        system.debug('Exception in Approval Process submision and error is--->'+ex);

        PSABatchUtil.trackErrorLogs(CLASS_NAME, 'submitForApproval',
                                    'Exception Line Number:' + ex.getLineNo() +
                                    'Exception Type' + ex.getType()+                                                             
                                    'Exception Message' + ex.getmessage());
    }
}
```

**Test class**

Assign any invalid values from test class to `processDefinitionNameOrId`.

```
Account testdelAcc=new Account(Name = 'Test DelAcc');

YourClass cls = new YourClass();

    insert testdelAcc;
    List<Account> lstAccount = new List<Account>();
    lstAccount.add(testdelAcc);
    cls.processDefinitionNameOrId = 'any invalid processDefinitionNameOrId';
    cls.submitForApproval(lstAccount);
    //check any values create in PSABatchUtil.trackErrorLogs 
}
```

Comment: Is it not possible to over catch block without passing additional parameter in the method?

Comment: yes, that can be possible. find updated answer

Comment: unfortunately it is not covering the catch part even after making changes suggested by you :(

Comment: you could check any values created in PSABatchUtil.trackErrorLogs

Comment: I often add a very long string for the record name - currently the limit is 80 chars - make it longer and it causes the save to fail and you enter the catch block.